# Header Widget in Gtk.TreeViewColumn

Tags: font-size, gtk3, gtktreeview

There is a Treeview with several TreeViewColumns. Because the default font-size is to big for my usage, I need to set the font-size in the TreeViewColumn Header.

I tried to following:

```
tvc = Gtk.TreeViewColumn()
tvcl = Gtk.Label("Test")
tvc.set_widget(tvcl)
```

But the Header of the Column is empty then.
If it's possible to change the font of the TreeViewColumn().title, this would be enaugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using python (from the code), here's an example:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Pango

tvc           = Gtk.TreeViewColumn (None, renderer, col)
custom_header = Gtk.Label ('Test')
tvc.set_widget (custom_header)
tvc.get_widget ().override_font (Pango.FontDescription.from_string ('8') )
tvc.get_widget ().show_all ()
```

Comment: The first way is not working for me. The field remains empty. And for the second one I get an exception, that the widget is None.

Comment: they are one single code. not alternative. so you need a set_widget first before you get get_widget, if not it will throw error. (I have practice this in my projects )

Comment: I finally figured it out... window.show_all() is not showing this Label. You have to call the show() method on the Label seperately